# A confusion regarding circular functions of real numbers

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I recently started $11^{th}$ grade **Trigonometry**.

Prior to this, I learnt about the three general systems of angle measurement, mainly the *Circular System of Angles*, dealing with *radians*

The very first section in the first chapter related to Trigonometry was regarding Trigonometric Functions of Real Numbers.

Shouldn't Trigonometric Functions have angles as inputs, in *degrees*, *grades*, *radians* or some other angle unit.

I did read about the relationship between real numbers and radian measures. I think I misunderstood some part of it.

It doesn't mean that $x^c = x$, right? In my opinion, it means that if $x^c$ is some angle, then $x \in \Bbb R$. Which one of the above mentioned assumptions is right?

I also am confused about the term **radian measure**. In my opinion, it means that if $\theta = x^c$, then $x$ is called the radian measure of $\theta$. Am I right here as well?

If I'm right in both of these cases, does the term *trigonometric functions of real numbers* mean that $sin$ $x$ is a way of saying $sin(x^c)$, since the superscript $^c$ is usually omitted while writing radians?

This might sound like a simple question but its really confusing for me. Please let me know about any misconceptions I might have about *radians* and also what the right thing is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radians and degrees are two different *units* of angle measure. Like we measure length in metres or time in seconds, we measure angles in radians. Trigonometric functions do take angles as inputs in both units. So,
$\sin 60^o , \sin \frac{\pi}{3}$ are both equivalent, just as $100\ cm$ is equivalent to a meter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so basically, when we write $sin \dfrac{\pi}{3}$, we mean $sin \Big ( \dfrac {\pi}{3} \Big )^c = sin(60^o) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and for any angle $x^c$, radian measure does mean $x$, and the relationship between real number and radian measures tells that if $x^c$ is any angle, then $x \in \Bbb R$, right?

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu Yes, exactly.

Comment: You have no idea how confused I was earlier and how thankful I am now!

Comment: That’s good for you!

Comment: I'm confused again. Didn't quite get @J.G.'s answer. Please check out the comment and let me know if you can explain it to me.

Comment: I revisited this question today and noticed that you said that $x^c$ and $x$ have different dimensions. But aren't angle measures in radians, degrees etc dimensionless, which would mean that the dimensions of both $x^c$ and $x$, which is a real number are the same...

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu That was wrong. Both are dimensionless, and hence have the same dimension.

Answer (score 1):

An arc of a radius-$r$ circle subtending an angle $\theta$ at its centre has length $s=kr\theta$ for some constant $k$, which depends on the units in which you measure angles. Regardless of that choice, $\theta$ being a [dimensionless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity) number implies $k$ is too. If we work with degrees, $k=\frac{\pi}{180}$; if we work with radians, $k=1$, which is the motive for using radians. So now $s=r\theta$, angles are dimensionless, and "$1$ radian" is just a fancy name for $1$. Why we even *mention* radians given this fact is another question, [which I've addressed before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3530650). But if you bear this point in mind, all your concerns evaporate. For example, $\sin0.3$ is synonymous with $\sin(0.3\,\text{radians})$, because $0.3$ is synonymous with $0.3\,\text{radians}$.

Comment: The answer that you linked stated that a quantity being dimensionless doesn't mean that it is unit-less. So, what does it mean for a quantity to be dimensionless? What exactly is meant by **dimensions** here?

Comment: So, when we say : trigonometric functions of real numbers, we mean trigonometric functions of angles, right? But, how? I just can't get it. Also, if 1 radian is just a fancy name for 1, what is the points of units? Pardon me if I'm being annoying, I'm just so confused...

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu I think what J.G. means  is that its usage is not super strict. Writing $\sin 1$ would be a shorter and more relaxed way of writing what would actually mean $\sin (1 \, radian)$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, let's wait till he confirms it...

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu You know how rectangles have area $A=hw$? Here $h$ and $w$ each have the dimension of length, say $L$, whereas $A$ has dimension $L^2$. You can work out the dimension of any one variable from the other two, e.g. $[h]=[A]/[w]=L^2/L=L$. In some cases all exponents would be $0$, so the quantity is dimensionless, like $\theta=s/r$. But it makes sense to have units sometimes, because (as per my link) you don't want to confuse angles with solid angles or LD50s.

Comment: I think I get it partly but I'm still not sure about what I actually wanna know to be honest. I will let you know if I have any further questions. Thanks!